# Image processing on a microcontroller

Tags: image-processing

Is it possible to do image processing on a microcontroller unit using c++ and raw image from a camera sensor as input? Useless sentence because quality standards.

Comment: Can you please rephrase that?

Comment: What do you mean by this:  "Useless sentence because quality standards."
Please provide more information on your embedded system and the image...

Comment: I want to compress images using a microcntroller programmed in c++. Does the language permit it?

Comment: you can do whatever you want with c++
question is if you have enough memory for that and if your mcu is fast enough to do the job in the required time.

Comment: Now that's another problem.

Comment: you can try RLE compression (like PCX) that does not need to have whole image loaded in memory and require just few variables and is fast. The main problem would be color quantization but you can use [dithering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214) if you do not need lossless compression.