# Algorithm for many images and their color palettes

Tags: javascript, image, algorithm, sorting, colors

For a project I'm looking for an algorithm to convert a lot of images to paletted images, which can share same palettes.

---

## The short story

**Given:**

- A list of **images (RGB)**, which already have the final colors which should be used.

**Result:**

- A list of **images (indiced)**
- A list of **palettes**
- Multiple **RGB images** can be converted to **one indiced image** by using **different palettes**.
- I want to use the minimum amount of images required with the minimum amount of palettes required.

**Limitations:**

- There is a maximum of *n* palettes
- There is a maximum of *m* colors per palette
- There is a maximum of *u* images which can be generated in the result

**What is my problem:**

- I don't know how to build the algorithm so it can decide whether any previous decision was wrong for future problems. (see below)
- I don't know how to solve rearranging palette colors and image data, because rearranging **one** image data might lead to follow up problems of rearranging which can end in an endless rearranging battle :D (see below)

---

## Here is the full story

### The result

So this here should be the **result**: In this case one color index table (aka indiced image) generates two different RGB images using two different palettes.

[image: Image rendering process]

### The first steps

As the input files all are RGB images, we need to convert them into palettes with their matching color indices first.

In the following image you can see how the algorithm could start working with the first three images:

1. **Convert** them into **palettes** and **color-indices**
2. **Check** whether **two images** share the **same color indices**, if so, we can **reuse the color indices** but create a palette (not required!)
3. Otherwise we could **add** the four **new colors** to the **first palette** and **create a new color index**. (Not shown in this image)
4. For the third image, we found a palette which already contains all required colors, so we decide to reuse the palette but rearrange our color indices to match the existing palette.

[image: First steps in our algorithm]

### Let's get complicated!

So far so good. But how should we continue with the last image? It may share the color indices of the previous one, but it does not match any existing palette then. Actually it does not match any existing palette.

So the following image describes **the actual problem**: How to decide what's best for images? Creating a new palette, creating a new color index, what if everything would went good if we decided otherwise in the past? How can we find out?

[image: The problem]

### Rearranging

Well, those four images are still the simple case. Let's imagine the algorithm already processed a lot of images, and generated a palette. The next image in our input-image-list finds a matching palette, so it could easily just create new color-indices and be fine. But: The result should be a minimum of images and palettes, so there could be another way!

By checking **all** previous images, we found out, that we could use the existing palette **and** color indices of the previous image, but we have to rearrange the palette. And rearranging requires us to check **all** previous images whether they are okay with the rearranged palette.

As you can see: The colors palettes in the last step have been rearranged to match the same colors below. But this might have been a complicated process of rearranging a lot of other images as well.

[image: Rearranging images]

---

Thank you in advance for any tips of how to implement such an algorithm, or what to search for or what already existing algorithms generate the nearly same result.

---

## Edit

Here is a real life example image with some graphics stolen from an old amiga game:

[image: Tileset]

This tileset contains 256 RGB images of 16*16 pixel. Each of this images is a tile which should be processed by the algorithm. The first few images are equal to each other, but later on there are several other images. It is possible to break down the palettes into **a maximum of 6 palettes with 16 colors** but with the limitation of always having the first color being a transparent color. (so actually its 15 colors per palette)

In this example its easy to reuse the same ColorIndices for the 4 colored keys, doors and diamants.

This is an example generated palette:
[image: Generated palette example]

---

## Edit No. 2

Here is another example I took out of an old game:

[image: Tileset]

The palette could look like this one:

[image: Palette]

Comment: +1 Interesting problem. Do you need to exactly match the colors? If not you might group together similar colors like this [Effective gif/image color quantization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214). Did you consider [dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214)?  That would need single palette for all the images ... or group the images by major colors and design special palette for each group lowering the noise ... Also do you really need "minimal" solution or close enough would be good too?

Comment: @Spektre Thank you! Actually the input RGB images will already have only the final colors (limited to n colors) and don't need to be modified anymore. It might be allowed to join nearly equal colors, but that's not part of this problem :) Its more about merging all image palettes into one palette. The "minimal" solution would be nice, but close enough is also good enough, I guess. It might also be possible by time that there actually is no solution.

Comment: Very nice question. If I understood you correctly, you're trying to minimize the _number of palettes_ while not exceeding _m_. What I did not understand is _u_. Arent you trying to fit as many images as possible into one palette? Why is there a limit to the amount of images assigned to a palette then?

Comment: Actually the problem is used for a tool for a Super Nintendo game project. The resulted images will be a used for a tileset (each image is one tile). The SNES is limited to 16 (or 8) palettes each having 16 colors. Also, because of limited RAM, the amount of images should be reduced as best as possible. Most developers would simply use a static tileset with a static palette for each game map, but I'd like to have a dynamic generated tileset with a dynamic generated palette. :) There can be unlimited images per palette, if they can share the colors.

Comment: how much bits per channel (r,g,b) for the palette? The low limits should allow to use brute force Genere&Test methods. With added some heuristics ... Also I would start with palettes only (ignoring images) as starters ... they not relevant unless lossy color encoding is in place. You should provide a sample input so we can have some common and valid test case to compare possible methods. We need to know all the limiting numbers.

Comment: @Spektre its a 15 bit color, each channel having 5 bits. I edited the post and attached a real world example to the end with a palette manually generated. :)

Comment: @BenjaminSchulte Today I got some time/mood for this see the result (in form of answer) but as mentioned before this is not the optimal solution just optimized by a simple heuristics so it probably could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my first naive approach for your sample input is even better than your reference:

[image: result]

On the left is your input image, in the middle is sprite output using global `group[]` palettes only without the empty sprites. On the right are unique palettes  sorted by group and in the right most column is the group palette representing that group.

As you can see I have just 5x 16 color palettes instead of 6. The first color index 0 is reserved for transparent color (I hard-coded white as I do not have access to the original indexed colors). The Algorithm is like this:

1. **init sprites**

   Each sprite must have its palette and index of global palette used.
2. **structures**

   I needed 2 lists of palettes for this. One is list of all unique palettes used at once (the whole image/frame) I call it `pal[]` and the other is called `group[]` and holds the final merged palettes to be used.
3. **populate `pal[]`**

   so just extract all palettes from all the sprites ... test for uniqueness (that is just to boost performance of the `O(n^2)` searches). To do this I sorted the palettes so I can directly compare them in `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`.
4. **grouping palettes**

   Take first ungrouped palette and create new group with it. Then check all other ungrouped palettes (`O(n^2)`) and if mergable then merge them. By mergable I mean the processed `pal[i]` have at least 50% of the colors present in the `group[j]` and all the missing colors can still fit into the `group[j]`. If the case mark `pal[i]` as a `group[j]` member and add the missing colors to `group[j]`. Then repeat #4 until no ungrouped palette is left.
5. **now reindex the sprites to match the `group[]` palettes**

**Here simple C++ code for this:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int _sprite_size=16;      // resolution
const int _palette_size=16;     // colors per palette
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class palette   // sprite palette
    {
public:
    int pals;                   // num of colors
    DWORD pal[_palette_size];   // palete colors
    int group;                  // group index

    // inline constructors (you can ignore this)
    palette()   {}
    palette(palette& a) { *this=a; }
    ~palette()  {}
    palette* operator = (const palette *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //palette* operator = (const palette &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    void draw(TCanvas *can,int x,int y,int sz,int dir)  // render palette to GDI canvas at (x,y) with square size sz and direction dir = { 0,90,180,270 } deg
        {
        int i;
        color c;
        for (i=0;i<pals;i++)
            {
            c.dd=pal[i]; rgb2bgr(c);
            can->Pen->Color=TColor(0x00202020);
            can->Brush->Color=TColor(c.dd);
            can->Rectangle(x,y,x+sz,y+sz);
            if (dir==  0) x+=sz;
            if (dir== 90) y-=sz;
            if (dir==180) x-=sz;
            if (dir==270) y+=sz;
            }
        }
    void sort() // bubble sort desc
        {
        int i,e,n=pals; DWORD q;
        for (e=1;e;n--)
         for (e=0,i=1;i<n;i++)
          if (pal[i-1]<pal[i])
           { q=pal[i-1]; pal[i-1]=pal[i]; pal[i]=q; e=1; }
        }
    int operator == (palette &a) { if (pals!=a.pals) return 0; for (int i=0;i<pals;i++) if (pal[i]!=a.pal[i]) return 0; return 1; }
    int merge(palette &p)   // return true and merge if this and p are similar and mergable palettes
        {
        int equal=0,mising=0,i,j;
        DWORD m[_palette_size]; // mising palette colors
        for (i=0;i<p.pals;i++)
            {
            m[mising]=p.pal[i];
            mising++;
            for (j=0;j<pals;j++)
             if (p.pal[i]==pal[j])
                {
                mising--;
                equal++;
                }
            }
        if (equal+equal<p.pals) return 0;   // at least half of colors must be present
        if (pals+mising>_palette_size) return 0;    // and the rest must fit in
        for (i=0;i<mising;i++) { pal[pals]=m[i]; pals++; }
        return 1;
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class sprite    // sprite
    {
public:
    int xs,ys;                              // resoltuon
    BYTE pix[_sprite_size][_sprite_size];   // pixel data (indexed colors)
    palette pal;                            // original palette
    int gpal;                               // global palette

    // inline constructors (you can ignore this)
    sprite()    {}
    sprite(sprite& a) { *this=a; }
    ~sprite()   {}
    sprite* operator = (const sprite *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //sprite* operator = (const sprite &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
List<sprite> spr;   // all sprites
List<palette> pal;  // all palettes
List<palette> group;// merged palettes
picture pic0,pic1,pic2; // input, output and debug images
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void compute() // this is the main code you need to call/investigate
    {
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;

    int e,i,j,ix,x,y,xx,yy;
    palette p,*pp;
    DWORD c;
    // [load image and convert to indexed 16 color sprites]
    // you can ignore this part of code as you already got your sprites with palettes...
    pic0.load("SNES_images.png");
    // process whole image
    spr.num=0; sprite s,*ps;
    for (y=0;y<pic0.ys;y+=_sprite_size)
     for (x=0;x<pic0.xs;x+=_sprite_size)
        {
        // let white transparent color be always index 0
        s.pal.pals=1;
        s.pal.pal[0]=0x00F8F8F8;
        s.gpal=-1;
        e=0;
        // proces sprite image
        for (yy=0;yy<_sprite_size;yy++)
         for (xx=0;xx<_sprite_size;xx++)
            {
            // match color with palette
            c=pic0.p[y+yy][x+xx].dd&0x00F8F8F8; // 15 bit RGB 5:5:5 to 32 bit RGB
            for (ix=-1,i=0;i<s.pal.pals;i++)
             if (s.pal.pal[i]==c) { ix=i; break; }
            // add new color if no match found
            if (ix<0)
                {
                if (s.pal.pals>=_palette_size)
                    {
                    // fatal error: invalid input data
                    ix=-1;
                    break;
                    }
                 ix=s.pal.pals;
                 s.pal.pal[s.pal.pals]=c;
                 s.pal.pals++;
                 }
            s.pix[yy][xx]=ix; e|=ix;
            }
        if (e) spr.add(s);  // ignore empty sprites
        }

    // [global palette list]
    // here starts the stuff you need
    // cretae list pal[] of all unique palettes from sprites spr[]
    pal.num=0;
    for (i=0,ps=spr.dat;i<spr.num;i++,ps++)
        {
        p=ps->pal; p.sort(); ix=-1;
        for (x=0;x<pal.num;x++) if (pal[x]==p) { ix=x; break; }
        if (ix<0) { ix=pal.num; pal.add(p); }
        ps->gpal=ix;
        }

    // [palette gropus]
    // creates a list group[] with merged palette from all the pal[] in the same group
    group.num=0;
    for (i=0;i<pal.num;i++) pal[i].group=-1;
    for (i=0;i<pal.num;i++)
        {
        if (pal[i].group<0)
            {
            pal[i].group=group.num; group.add(pal[i]);
            pp=&group[group.num-1];
            }
        for (j=i+1;j<pal.num;j++)
         if (pal[j].group<0)
          if (pp->merge(pal[j]))
           pal[j].group=pp->group;
        }

    // [update sprites to match group palette]
    for (i=0,ps=spr.dat;i<spr.num;i++,ps++)
        {
        pp=&pal[ps->gpal];  // used global palette
        ps->gpal=pp->group; // update gpal in sprite to point to group palette (you can copy group palette into sprite instead)
        pp=&group[ps->gpal];// used group palette
        // compute reindex table
        int idx[_palette_size];
        for (x=0;x<ps->pal.pals;x++)
         for (idx[x]=0,y=0;y<pp->pals;y++)
          if (ps->pal.pal[x]==pp->pal[y])
           {idx[x]=y; break; }
        // proces sprite image
        for (yy=0;yy<_sprite_size;yy++)
         for (xx=0;xx<_sprite_size;xx++)
          if (ps->pix[yy][xx])  // ignore transparent pixels
           ps->pix[yy][xx]=idx[ps->pix[yy][xx]];
        }

    // [render groups]
    e=6;
    xx=(e*_palette_size);
    yy=(e*pal.num);
    pic2.resize(xx+e+xx,yy);
    pic2.clear(0);
    for (x=0,y=0,ix=0;ix<group.num;ix++,y+=e)
        {
        group[ix].draw(pic2.bmp->Canvas,x+xx,y,e,0);
        for (i=0;i<pal.num;i++)
         if (pal[i].group==ix)
            {
            pal[i].draw(pic2.bmp->Canvas,x,y,e,0);
            y+=e;
            }
        }

    // [render sprites to pic1 for visual comparison using merged palettes]
    pic1.resize(pic0.xs,pic0.ys);
    pic1.clear(0);
    for (x=0,y=0,i=0,ps=spr.dat;i<spr.num;i++,ps++)
        {
        pp=&group[ps->gpal];
        // proces sprite image
        for (yy=0;yy<_sprite_size;yy++)
         for (xx=0;xx<_sprite_size;xx++)
          if (ps->pix[yy][xx])  // ignore transparent pixels
           pic1.p[y+yy][x+xx].dd=pp->pal[ps->pix[yy][xx]];
        x+=_sprite_size; if (x+_sprite_size>pic1.xs) { x=0;
        y+=_sprite_size; if (y+_sprite_size>pic1.ys) break; }
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just ignore the **VCL** and **GDI** rendering stuff.

**I use my own picture class for images so some members are:**

`xs,ys` is size of image in pixels

`p[y][x].dd` is pixel at `(x,y)` position as 32 bit integer type

`clear(color)` clears entire image with `color`

`resize(xs,ys)` resizes image to new resolution

`bmp` is **VCL** encapsulated **GDI** Bitmap with `Canvas` access

`pf` holds actual pixel format of the image:

```
enum _pixel_format_enum
    {
    _pf_none=0, // undefined
    _pf_rgba,   // 32 bit RGBA
    _pf_s,      // 32 bit signed int
    _pf_u,      // 32 bit unsigned int
    _pf_ss,     // 2x16 bit signed int
    _pf_uu,     // 2x16 bit unsigned int
    _pixel_format_enum_end
    };
```

`color` and pixels are encoded like this:

```
union color
    {
    DWORD dd; WORD dw[2]; byte db[4];
    int i; short int ii[2];
    color(){}; color(color& a){ *this=a; }; ~color(){}; color* operator = (const color *a) { dd=a->dd; return this; }; /*color* operator = (const color &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
```

The bands are:

```
enum{
    _x=0,   // dw
    _y=1,

    _b=0,   // db
    _g=1,
    _r=2,
    _a=3,

    _v=0,   // db
    _s=1,
    _h=2,
    };
```

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

Comment: +1 thank you very much for your effort on this :) I tried out your approach and it looks good for the example. As I can see it ignores the thing about "sharing Images with same ColorIndices using different palettes", but I checked and saw that there are not soo many cases. I added a second example I finished yesterday. This algorithm generates 8 palettes (Could be easily compressed to 7 by some more code lines, that's no problem), but the original uses 5 palettes. I though about maybe using some kind of astar algorithm on this one? In any case: thank you very much! :D

Comment: you can add any kind of tweaks like create group only from biggest ungrouped palette, or sort the palettes by somethig first, or try to merge again after any color change in actula group palette, changing thresholds in mergable etc ... This is just start point I would try to sort the palettes by similarity to actually processed group palette and add the most similar first ...