# How to fix the dithering method to create a color gradient?

Tags: c++, algorithm, serialization, graphics

There is a program that builds a matrix for a color gradient from white to black. Then, a dithering algorithm is applied to the matrix to eliminate the "stripes". 4 methods of dithering are implemented: Ordered, Random, Floyd-Steinberg, Jarvis-Judice-Ninke. First, I create a matrix of a certain size, convert it to a gradient, and output the result to a file format .pgm, type P5. If I translate the file into .png, I get the following image:

[image]

However, when you zoom in on the image, you can see the stripes (if you look closely):

[image]

This is the result of the program without dithering. The problem is that if you apply one of the dithering algorithms to the matrix, then stripes remain on the image. The result suggests that dithering does not work. What could be wrong? Do I need to use dithering first, and then build a gradient? Or the error is that you need to create a matrix of float or double type? How can I fix it?

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> make_gradient(int height, int width)
{
    assert(height > 0 && width > 0);

    int cf = height / 255;
    int color = 0;
    vector<vector<int>> result(height, vector<int>(width));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i += cf)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cf; ++j)
        {
            fill(result[i + j].begin(), result[i + j].end(), color % 255);
        }
        color++;
    }
    stable_sort(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> ordered_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    int ditherSize = 4;
    int diterLookup[] = { 0, 8, 2, 10, 12, 4, 14, 6, 3, 11, 1, 9, 15, 7, 13, 5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int xlocal = i%ditherSize;
            int ylocal = j%ditherSize;
            int requiredShade = diterLookup[xlocal + ylocal * 4] * 255 / 16;
            if ((requiredShade > 0) && (requiredShade < 1))
            {
                if (requiredShade >= (result[i][j] % 1)) {
                    result[i][j] = floor(result[i][j]);
                }
                else {
                    result[i][j] = ceil(result[i][j]);
                }
            }
            else requiredShade = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> random_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int requiredShade = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            if ((requiredShade > 0) && (requiredShade < 1))
            {
                if (requiredShade >= (result[i][j] % 1)) {
                    result[i][j] = floor(result[i][j]);
                }
                else {
                    result[i][j] = ceil(result[i][j]);
                }
            }
            else requiredShade = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> fs_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int oldpixel = result[i][j];
            int newpixel = round(result[i][j]);
            result[i][j] = newpixel;
            int quanterror = oldpixel - newpixel;
            if (j < width - 1) {
                result[i][j + 1] += quanterror * 7 / 16;
            }
            if (i < height - 1) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    result[i + 1][j - 1] += quanterror * 3 / 16;
                }
                result[i + 1][j] += quanterror * 5 / 16;
                if (j < width - 1) {
                    result[i + 1][j + 1] += quanterror * 1 / 16;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> jjn_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int oldpixel = result[i][j];
            int newpixel = round(result[i][j]);;
            result[i][j] = newpixel;
            int quanterror = oldpixel - newpixel;
            if (j < width - 1) {
                result[i][j + 1] += quanterror * 7 / 48;
                if (j<width - 2)
                    result[i][j + 2] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
            }

            if (i < height - 1) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    if (j > 1)
                        result[i + 1][j - 2] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                    result[i + 1][j - 1] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
                }

                result[i + 1][j] += quanterror * 7 / 48;
                if (j < width - 1) {
                    result[i + 1][j + 1] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
                    if (j < width - 2)
                        result[i + 1][j + 2] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                }
            }

            if (i < height - 2) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    if (j>1)
                        result[i + 2][j - 2] += quanterror * 1 / 48;
                    result[i + 2][j - 1] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                }
                result[i + 2][j] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
                if (j < width - 1) {
                    result[i + 2][j + 1] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                    if (j < width - 2)
                        result[i + 2][j + 2] += quanterror * 1 / 48;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 5) {
        cout << "usage:" << endl << "prog.exe <filename> <width> <height> <dithering>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    stringstream w(argv[2]);
    stringstream h(argv[3]);
    stringstream d(argv[4]);
    int numcols, numrows, dithering;

    if (!(w >> numcols)) {
        cout << "width is not a number" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (numcols < 1) {
        cout << "width must be more than zero" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!(h >> numrows)) {
        cout << "height is not a number" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (numrows < 1) {
        cout << "height must be more than zero" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!(d >> dithering)) {
        cout << "dithering is not a number" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (dithering < 0 || dithering>4) {
        cout << "dithering must be [0-4]" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    srand(time(0));
    ofstream file;

    file.open(argv[1]);

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "can't open file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    file << "P5" << "\n";

    file << numrows << " " << numcols << "\n";

    file << 255 << "\n";

    vector<vector<int>> pixmap{ make_gradient(numrows, numcols) };
    switch (dithering) {
    case 1:
        pixmap = ordered_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    case 2:
        pixmap = random_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    case 3:
        pixmap = fs_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    case 4:
        pixmap = jjn_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    for_each(pixmap.begin(), pixmap.end(), [&](const auto& v) {
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<char>{file, ""});
    });

    file.close();

}
```

Comment: You have a lot of issues with integer math.  For example, `if ((requiredShade > 0) && (requiredShade < 1))` will always be false.  `result[i][j] % 1` will always be 0.

Comment: I fixed this error:

double requiredShade = ...;

if ((requiredShade >= 0) && (requiredShade < 1))

Comment: elcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
You've posted *visual* output, rather than the erroneous values, and there seems to be no debugging attempt.  You've included I/O overhead unrelated to the problem.

Comment: what is the resolution of your gradient if its bigger than 256 then no dithering is capable of removing the stripes as they are singular step in illumination your "gfx is capable of" ... dithering is used to reduce used colors number while preserving the color information as much as possible. In such case the best you can obtain is added noise to image but that usually somehow degrades the quality of image visually. If not the case see [simple dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214)

Answer (score 4):

It's interesting to see you using dither to get rid of those bands that you can hardly see -- in the old days we would only dither when we had to render in 4 bits per channel or so.

Anyway...  Your first problem is that before you use dithering to reduce your gradient to 256 levels, you have to render it at *more* than 256 levels.  `make_gradient` should probably be rendering the gradient at 65536 levels or even floating point.

Your second problem is, it seems to me, that your dithering is currently doing nothing at all.   `result[i][j]` is an *integer*, so when you say something like `result[i][j] = floor(result[i][j]);` (I guess you ignore the compiler warnings about the conversion), it does *nothing*.  If you were generating your gradient in floats that problem would go away too.

If you fix these problems, then your dither can work, however none of these dither methods is really optimal for operating at such closely spaced levels.  There may still be banding artifacts of some kind remaining when you're done (although you'd have to look *really* closely to see them).  To make your results look as good as possible, you should really use a TPDF dither with amplitude equal to two quantization levels.  With coarsely space levels, this looks noisier than some of your other choices, but is statistically more uniform and will look better when the levels are finely spaced.

It's also easy -- just add two random numbers between -0.5 and 0.5 to each pixel before quantizing to integers.

TPDF is mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither , but it's most important because it's the type of dither used in sampling for signal processing to make sure that the quantization doesn't cause any first or second order artifacts.

EDIT:

I appreciate that you've been working on this, so here's the code to create the dithered gradient in final form in one step:

```
vector<vector<int>> make_dithered_gradient(int height, int width)
{
    assert(height > 0 && width > 0);

    vector<vector<int>> result(height, vector<int>(width));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        // the target shade for each line of pixels is the average
        // ideal gradient value in that line, which is the same as the
        // ideal value in the middle of the line
        double target = ((double)i+0.5)*255.0/height;
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            double dither = ((double)rand()-(double)rand())/RAND_MAX;
            int val = (int)round(target+dither);
            if (val < 0)
                val = 0;
            if (val > 255)
                val = 255;
            result[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I managed to get the dithering to work,  though I haven't managed to get the proportion of the darker pixels to be smaller in certain areas.When using random dithering, I get the following result: http://prntscr.com/me6phc
When you zoom in on the image, you can see that artifacts appear on the image.
http://prntscr.com/me6q7x
This is the code for the method: https://pastebin.com/vLmA2LgC
This result is closer to the required. How can I fix it?

Comment: `double dither = ((double)rand() - (double)rand())/RAND_MAX;` `result[i,j] = round(tmp+dither)*8.0`.  No `if` or `modf` or `requiredShade`. You'll have to clamp results < 0 or > 255.  I assume you're doing the *8 just to make the dithering more noticeable.

Comment: That dithering looks very nice -- you can no longer see the bands.  The mess at the top is because you didn't check for results < 0

Comment: I get the feeling you're running around in circles a bit in this, and your original gradient initialization is weird, so see edit^^

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. Looks like I finally got the idea.  Now I am trying to fix the remaining methods. At first I tried to change the ordered dithering in two ways. This is the first option: https://pastebin.com/ph3HzQxm. In this case, dithering doesn't work at all. The second option: https://pastebin.com/uQ57stNC. And I get this result: http://prntscr.com/mep1ka. FS dithering and JJN dithering look correct. For these methods I simply removed the third argument as in random dithering, but now, as a result of their work, a completely black image is obtained.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about target and val in last two methods, because  without them it’s impossible to build a gradient. I tried to fix FS method in this way: https://pastebin.com/kiKv5SaT. Is it correct? Result looks fine, but little stripes are still visible: http://prntscr.com/meplsi. As I understand it, for the last two methods it is impossible to completely get rid of the bands, as in the random dithering.

Comment: I fix this line for ordered dithering: 

double dither = ditherLookup[xlocal + ylocal * 4];

The result is close to the desired: http://prntscr.com/mevxph