# How to render an image on a device when the device does not support whole color the image have?

Tags: graphics

I have a image need to display on a device, but this device only has 255 color (some device maybe less), for some color it does not support, does it choose a 'nearest' color? or some other way?

As @CherryDT's comment, maybe use nearest color or dithering or just refuse to render, dose there other ways to handle it?

Comment: Depending on the software that renders the image, it may use a nearest color or dithering or just refuse to render it entirely. We can't know without knowing how the software works!

Comment: depends on a lot of factors for example what colors you got at disposal (configurable pallete or fixed one, color depth, used colors and shades), what is the input image (photo, painting, cartoon,text ...) what is acceptable output (noise, color error, pattern error, ...) usually 2 basic approaches are used (and or combined): 1. [dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214) 2. [quantization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214). There are many algorithms for both approaches differing in speed, memory consumption and accuracy.