# compare two components with their colors

Tags: image-processing, colors, opencv, rgb, hsl

i want to compare to components with their filled colors if they are equal or not
i do the following algorithm , i do averaging for the rgb as following

```
                double avg1 =(comp[0].Red+comp[0].Blue+comp[0].Green)/3;
                double avg2 =(comp[1].Red+comp[1].Blue+comp[1].Green)/3;
```

then compare them as  following

```
                      double ratio  = avg1/avg2 ;
                      if(ratio > 0.8 && ratio < 1.2){} //then they are supposed to be equal
```

but this way isn't accurate at all

after searching i found that the best way is converting the image to HSL space and compare
but i can't get how i compare 2 colors ?!! [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492211/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-how-close-two-colors-are-to-each-other/492230#492230)

in other words after converting the image into HSL space what can i do ?!

help please !!

**modification** to the question for more clarification 
 i mean with component (sequence of points) so in the averaging step actually i revisit all the points calculating the sum of the average of rgb for each pixel , then do averaging over the total number of the points

Comment: What kind of comparison are you looking to do, exactly? "Close enough"? What's your use case?

Comment: actually i want to get if two components are having the same color ?! then group them together etc.,,

Answer (score 1):

Convert to HSL and use the difference in H (hue) to group colors.

Answer (score 1):

So if your question is "after converting the image into HSL space what can i do ?!" then here goes:

1. convert the RGB image you've loaded to HSL using `cvCvtColor()` with the `CV_RGB2HLS` flag (the HSL image should be 3-channel, naturally)
2. make three single-channel images (of same size) for the H, L, S channels to be separated into
3. `cvSplit( hls, h, l, s, 0 )` to separate the HSL image into channels
4. Now the h_image will be just like any single-channel grayscale image. So after extracting components (do this from thresholding the RGB image, sometimes Hue channel image looks weird :P) simply compare the colors in the hue image that correspond to their co-ordinates.

Hope this helps.