# Color - Finding the closest color

Tags: java, android, colors

I was following the guidelines as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors), but when my android app examines a picture taken in a well-lit room and tries to match every color to the closest basic color (black, red, blue, green, etc.), most of the colors are associated with black. I have no idea why this happens and I have spent 3 hours examining my code to find out where the flaw was. Can anyone suggest where my error is? 
Here is my code:

```
public double getMinEValue(int color1, int color2) {
    double result_value = 0;
    double[] color1_values = getColorValues(color1);
    double[] color2_values = getColorValues(color2);
    double delta_L = color1_values[0] - color2_values[0];
    double delta_C = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(color1_values[1], 2)+Math.pow(color1_values[2], 2))-Math.sqrt(Math.pow(color2_values[1], 2)+Math.pow(color2_values[2], 2));
    double delta_a = color1_values[1]-color2_values[1];
    double delta_b = color1_values[2]-color2_values[2];
    double delta_H = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(delta_a, 2)+Math.pow(delta_b, 2)+Math.pow(delta_C, 2));
    double k_1 = 0.045; double k_2 = 0.015;
    double s_c = 1+k_1*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(color1_values[1], 2)+Math.pow(color1_values[2], 2));
    double s_h = 1+k_2*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(color1_values[1], 2)+Math.pow(color1_values[2], 2));
    result_value = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(delta_L, 2)+Math.pow((delta_C/s_c), 2)+Math.pow((delta_H/s_h), 2));
    return result_value;
}

public double[] getColorValues(int color1) {
    double[] return_value = new double[3];
    double r = Color.red(color1)/255;
    double g = Color.green(color1)/255;
    double b = Color.blue(color1)/255;
    double r_linear = makeLinear(r) * 100;
    double g_linear = makeLinear(g) * 100;
    double b_linear = makeLinear(b) * 100;
    double[][] matrix = {{0.4124, 0.3576, 0.1805}, {0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722}, {0.0193, 0.1192, 0.9508}};
    double[] linear_matrix = {r_linear, g_linear, b_linear};
    double[] result_matrix = new double[3];
    result_matrix = multiplyMatrices(matrix, linear_matrix);
    //double X_n = 109.85; double Y_n = 100.00; double Z_n = 35.58; // Illuminant A
    double X_n = 95.047; double Y_n = 100.00; double Z_n = 108.883; // D65
    double L_star = 116*f(result_matrix[1]/Y_n)-16;
    double a_star = 500*(f(result_matrix[0]/X_n)-f(result_matrix[1]/Y_n));
    double b_star = 200*(f(result_matrix[1]/Y_n)-f(result_matrix[2]/Z_n));
    return_value[0] = L_star; return_value[1] = a_star; return_value[2] = b_star;
    return return_value;
}

private double f(double t) {
    double return_value;
    if (Double.compare(t, Math.pow((6/29), 3)) > 0) {
        return_value = Math.pow(t, (1/3));
    } else {
        return_value = (1/3)*Math.pow((29/6), 2)*t+(4/29);
    }
    return return_value;
}

private double makeLinear(double c) {
    double return_value = 0;
    if (Double.compare(0.04045, c)<=0) {
        return_value = c/12.92;
    } else {
        double a = 0.055;
        return_value = Math.pow(((c + a) / (1 + a)), 2.4);
    }
    return return_value;
}

private double[] multiplyMatrices(double[][] matrix, double[] other_matrix) {
    double[] return_matrix = new double[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            return_matrix[i] += matrix[i][j]*other_matrix[j];
        }
    }
    return return_matrix;
}
```

Comment: You need to present a specific question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a whole lot of integer divisions that need to be floating point divisions.  You need to cast one of the operands of each division to `double`, or include a decimal point, to get these to work.  For example, you have

```
Color.red(color1)/255
```

which should be

```
Color.red(color1)/255.0
```

and you also have expressions like

```
(1/3)*Math.pow((29/6), 2)*t+(4/29);
```

which needs to be

```
(1.0/3)*Math.pow((29.0/6), 2)*t+(4.0/29);
```

and many others.  You have made this same mistake several times.