# prominent color from bitmap without using Palette Api Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

i Want to get Most prominent color Code like(Black,White, Blue etc etc)from bitmap without using Palette Api Android..Please Help

Comment: Palette is designed specifically for this case. Why are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: because i am not using v7 support library in my project... i dont want to use  it right now

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you need to do is essentially blur the bitmap and then pick out the pixel color. You can blur is simply by scaling it down to a small size and then enlarging it to a larger one (`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`). This will pixelate your bitmap. Then you obtain the color of the pixels (`Bitmap.getPixels(x,y)`).

Experiment with the scaling so that the final bitmap contains fewer colors as pixels.

Comment: i can get the color of the pixels... but how can i know that which color is most prominent than other colors in bitmap?

Comment: When you blur the image, only the prominent colors shows up. If a color appears only 1% in your bitmap, on blurring it, that color is lost. As I mentioned you need to experiment with blurring the bitmap.

Comment: ok let me try then i'll let you know when i done with it.. thanks for hint

Answer (score 0):

You want to get shades image? In any case, you need something like this:

```
import android.graphics.Color;

int reds = 0;
int blues = 0;
int greens = 0;

int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth()];
myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
for (int i=0; i<pixels.length; i++) {

int red = Color.red(colour);
int blue = Color.blue(colour);
int green = Color.green(colour);

/* Or it
    r = (pix[i]) >> 16 & 0xff;
    g = (pix[i]) >> 8 & 0xff;
    b = (pix[i]) & 0xff;*/
//int alpha = Color.alpha(colour);

if (red >= blue && red >= green) reds++;
if (blue >= red && blue >= green) blues++;
if (green >= blue && green >= red) greens++;
}
```

Comment: i managed to get color like this but Can you tell me how can i remove a specific color from bitmap? Although i managed to remove the color but it is not removing completely?

Comment: You need to get the color tones. But dude, you're asking have more of information without even+. Read it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors