# Compare UIColor similarity with percentage

Tags: swift, uicolor

I have following color,

```
let userskin = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#EFC1A2")

skinColor1.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#F0C6A9")
skinColor2.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#EACBBD")
skinColor3.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#EFC1A2")
skinColor4.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#F6D6C2")
skinColor5.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#F7D7BD")
```

I would like to compare `userskin` is how many percentage same with skinColor list. I want to chose the item base on the skin.

Comment: Start by converting the colors to HSB.

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors-for-similarity-difference