# How to check for the matching colors in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

I am scanning a Rubik cube by mobile camera. I am getting the colors of the sides, but even same colors have slightly different color value. Is there a way to detect this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two colors for similarity/difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors-for-similarity-difference)

Comment: Do you have any code to show so we can start helping?

Comment: @RyanSingh: Yes i wrote this basic one
                    
bool IsApproxColor (int j, Color32 col)
 {
 bool tmp = (col.r > GameConstants.GetColor (j).r - 30) && (col.r < Color(j).r + 30) && (col.g > Color (j).g - 30) && col.g < (Color (j).g + 30) && (col.b > Color (j).b - 30) && (col.b < Color (j).b + 30); return tmp; 
}