# How can I know the difference in percentage between one UIColor and another?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have a baseline `UIColor` (see below). How can I know how close another `UIColor` is to my baseline `UIColor`, let's say `.red` or `.blue` in this example.

Let's ignore the alpha channel.

Preferably I'd like a percentage returned, so I can print something like ".red color is a 40% match to your baseline color" or something like that.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am going to answer my own question here...

According to this [How to compare two colors for similarity/difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors-for-similarity-difference), in order to get the correct human perceived color difference value, we need to convert `UIColor`'s RGB to Lab. Then using Lab we can get the deltaE (i.e. difference between the two colors) value using the latest **CIEDE2000** formula.

Here's the Swift code based on this ***awesome*** UIColor extension set here: https://github.com/jathu/sweetercolor/blob/master/Sweetercolor/Sweetercolor.swift

This will get the deltaE between two colors:

```
/**
    Detemine the distance between two colors based on the way humans perceive them.
    Uses the Sharma 2004 alteration of the CIEDE2000 algorithm.
 
    - parameter compare color: A UIColor to compare.
 
    - returns: A CGFloat representing the deltaE
*/
func CIEDE2000(compare color: UIColor) -> CGFloat {
    // CIEDE2000, Sharma 2004 -> http://www.ece.rochester.edu/~gsharma/ciede2000/ciede2000noteCRNA.pdf
    
    func rad2deg(r: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return r * CGFloat(180/Double.pi)
    }
    
    func deg2rad(d: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return d * CGFloat(Double.pi/180)
    }
    
    let k_l = CGFloat(1), k_c = CGFloat(1), k_h = CGFloat(1)
    
    let LAB1 = self.LAB
    let L_1 = LAB1[0], a_1 = LAB1[1], b_1 = LAB1[2]
    
    let LAB2 = color.LAB
    let L_2 = LAB2[0], a_2 = LAB2[1], b_2 = LAB2[2]
    
    let C_1ab = sqrt(pow(a_1, 2) + pow(b_1, 2))
    let C_2ab = sqrt(pow(a_2, 2) + pow(b_2, 2))
    let C_ab  = (C_1ab + C_2ab)/2
    
    let G = 0.5 * (1 - sqrt(pow(C_ab, 7)/(pow(C_ab, 7) + pow(25, 7))))
    let a_1_p = (1 + G) * a_1
    let a_2_p = (1 + G) * a_2
    
    let C_1_p = sqrt(pow(a_1_p, 2) + pow(b_1, 2))
    let C_2_p = sqrt(pow(a_2_p, 2) + pow(b_2, 2))
    
    // Read note 1 (page 23) for clarification on radians to hue degrees
    let h_1_p = (b_1 == 0 && a_1_p == 0) ? 0 : (atan2(b_1, a_1_p) + CGFloat(2 * Double.pi)) * CGFloat(180/Double.pi)
    let h_2_p = (b_2 == 0 && a_2_p == 0) ? 0 : (atan2(b_2, a_2_p) + CGFloat(2 * Double.pi)) * CGFloat(180/Double.pi)
    
    let deltaL_p = L_2 - L_1
    let deltaC_p = C_2_p - C_1_p
    
    var h_p: CGFloat = 0
    if (C_1_p * C_2_p) == 0 {
        h_p = 0
    } else if fabs(h_2_p - h_1_p) <= 180 {
        h_p = h_2_p - h_1_p
    } else if (h_2_p - h_1_p) > 180 {
        h_p = h_2_p - h_1_p - 360
    } else if (h_2_p - h_1_p) < -180 {
        h_p = h_2_p - h_1_p + 360
    }
    
    let deltaH_p = 2 * sqrt(C_1_p * C_2_p) * sin(deg2rad(d: h_p/2))
    
    let L_p = (L_1 + L_2)/2
    let C_p = (C_1_p + C_2_p)/2
    
    var h_p_bar: CGFloat = 0
    if (h_1_p * h_2_p) == 0 {
        h_p_bar = h_1_p + h_2_p
    } else if fabs(h_1_p - h_2_p) <= 180 {
        h_p_bar = (h_1_p + h_2_p)/2
    } else if fabs(h_1_p - h_2_p) > 180 && (h_1_p + h_2_p) < 360 {
        h_p_bar = (h_1_p + h_2_p + 360)/2
    } else if fabs(h_1_p - h_2_p) > 180 && (h_1_p + h_2_p) >= 360 {
        h_p_bar = (h_1_p + h_2_p - 360)/2
    }
    
    let T1 = cos(deg2rad(d: h_p_bar - 30))
    let T2 = cos(deg2rad(d: 2 * h_p_bar))
    let T3 = cos(deg2rad(d: (3 * h_p_bar) + 6))
    let T4 = cos(deg2rad(d: (4 * h_p_bar) - 63))
    let T = 1 - rad2deg(r: 0.17 * T1) + rad2deg(r: 0.24 * T2) - rad2deg(r: 0.32 * T3) + rad2deg(r: 0.20 * T4)
    
    let deltaTheta = 30 * exp(-pow((h_p_bar - 275)/25, 2))
    let R_c = 2 * sqrt(pow(C_p, 7)/(pow(C_p, 7) + pow(25, 7)))
    let S_l =  1 + ((0.015 * pow(L_p - 50, 2))/sqrt(20 + pow(L_p - 50, 2)))
    let S_c = 1 + (0.045 * C_p)
    let S_h = 1 + (0.015 * C_p * T)
    let R_t = -sin(deg2rad(d: 2 * deltaTheta)) * R_c
    
    // Calculate total
    
    let P1 = deltaL_p/(k_l * S_l)
    let P2 = deltaC_p/(k_c * S_c)
    let P3 = deltaH_p/(k_h * S_h)
    let deltaE = sqrt(pow(P1, 2) + pow(P2, 2) + pow(P3, 2) + (R_t * P2 * P3))
    
    return deltaE
}
```

This is called within the above function (`func CIEDE2000`) to get the Lab colors from UIColor:

```
/**
    Get the CIE L*ab values.
 
    - returns: An array of three CGFloat numbers representing LAB respectively.
*/
var LAB: [CGFloat] {
    // http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=07#text7
    
    let XYZ = self.XYZ
    
    func LAB_helper(c: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.008856 < c ? pow(c, 1/3) : ((7.787 * c) + (16/116))
    }
    
    let X: CGFloat = LAB_helper(c: XYZ[0]/95.047)
    let Y: CGFloat = LAB_helper(c: XYZ[1]/100.0)
    let Z: CGFloat = LAB_helper(c: XYZ[2]/108.883)
    
    let L: CGFloat = (116 * Y) - 16
    let A: CGFloat = 500 * (X - Y)
    let B: CGFloat = 200 * (Y - Z)
    
    return [L, A, B]
}
```

Comment: I tested the LAB function above and found a possible problem with it. It uses pow() function to raise a number to the power of 1/3. However, 1/3 is treated by Swift as Int, which means it always raises the given number to the power of 0. That leads to a significant difference. I updated it to pow(c, Double(1)/3)

Answer (score 1):

[Color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).

You can find a formula for getting the distance between two colors.

> As most definitions of color difference are distances within a color space, the standard means of determining distances is the Euclidean distance. If one presently has an RGB (Red, Green, Blue) tuple and wishes to find the color difference, computationally one of the easiest is to consider R, G, B linear dimensions defining the color space.

[image]

> When the result should be computationally simple as well, it is often acceptable to remove the square root and simply use:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This let me down the right path. It looks like from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors-for-similarity-difference I may need to consider using the `deltaE` method though to get a more human perceived accurate result.

Comment: Of course, it'd be good to check which one is better for the human eye. It's interesting to get %80 similarity between black and green from [here](http://www.colortools.net/color_matcher.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
func testing(setColor: UIColor, myColor: UIColor)-> String{
    var finalSum : Float = 0.0
    for i in 0...2{
        var sum = setColor.cgColor.components![i] - myColor.cgColor.components![i]
        if sum < 0{
            sum = -sum
            finalSum = finalSum + Float(sum)
        }else{
            finalSum = finalSum + Float(sum)
        }
    }
    return "Colors match \(Int(finalSum*100/3))%"
}
```

use:-

`print(testing(setColor: .blue, myColor: .brown))`

i hope it will work for you :)